# zlib inflate returns Z_DATA_ERROR "Incorrect header check"

Tags: compression, zlib, deflate, spdy

I'm trying to develop my own SPDY support implementation on a web server, SPDY is a Google experimental protocol for reducing latency in loading web pages. Client/server interaction happens through a "stream", as is, a bidirectional exchange of SPDY information units, named "frames", between client and server. Some of these frames have a header block within, and this block is always compressed. I'm using following function (the web server is written in C) to decompress a "header block", compression/decompression algorithm is deflate, so zlib is the way:

```
int spdy_decompress_header_block( Byte* data, size_t data_len, unsigned char* processed, size_t* processed_len, z_stream* decomp) {

if (!decomp) {
    // I should return error...
    spdy_log_error("Error occurred getting decompressor!!!");
    return -1;
}

char decomp_buffer[HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE];
size_t decompressed_len = 0;
int rv = -1;

inflateReset(decomp);
decomp->next_in = data;
decomp->avail_in = data_len;
while (decomp->avail_in > 0) {

    decomp->next_out = (Byte*)decomp_buffer;
    decomp->avail_out = HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE;

    rv = inflate(decomp,Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

    if (rv == Z_NEED_DICT) {

        uLong dictionary_id = calculate_dictionary_id((Byte*)SPDY_dictionary, sizeof(SPDY_dictionary));

        if (decomp->adler == dictionary_id){

            rv = inflateSetDictionary(decomp, (Byte*)SPDY_dictionary, sizeof(SPDY_dictionary));
            rv = inflate(decomp, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        }

    }

    if ((rv == Z_OK) || ((rv == Z_BUF_ERROR) && (decomp->avail_in == 0))) {
        decompressed_len = HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE - decomp->avail_out;
        if (decompressed_len > 0) {
            memcpy(processed + *processed_len, decomp_buffer, decompressed_len);
            *processed_len += decompressed_len;
        }

    } else {
        if(rv == Z_DATA_ERROR){
            spdy_log_error("Error inflating headers:  Z_DATA_ERROR encountered" );
        }else{
            spdy_log_error("Error inflating headers!!!");
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
return *processed_len;
```

}

SPDY specifications advice for reusing same compressors/decompressors <strike>for each frame in a stream</strike> for each frame in a SPDY session (corresponding to a TCP connection), this way every header block is threated by z_stream with internal state already "warmed" by using a dictionary (also included in SPDY specifications).
Dictionary setting and z_stream initialization are succesfull, first block decompression works fine,  second frame block decompression fails in

> rv = inflate(decomp,Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

return value is -3 (Z_DATA_ERROR), decomp->msg is set to "Incorrect header check". Seems to me that inflate can't find zlib header. Compressing and uncompressing data is done by calling deflate() and inflate() with Z_SYNC_FLUSH as suggested by google specifications, I checked this in chromium (browser I actually use for testing) source code to be sure. 
First block (successfully decompresssed) is:

```
00111000 11101010 11011111 10100010 01010001 10110010 01100010 11100000 01100110 01100000
10000011 10100100 00010111 00000110 01111011 10111000 00001011 01110101 00110000 00101100
...
00001000 01001110 01001100 01001011 00101100 11001010 10000100 01101010 01100010 01100000
10000111 01000110 00001001 00000011 00000111 00101100 10100110 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 11111111 11111111
```

while second block (which is driving me mad) is:

```
00011010 01110110 00010001 00000011 00010000 01000000 10111001 10001001 00010101 10111010 10001001 11101001 10101001 10110110 00000110 00000000 00000001 01000100 01101110 11000100 00000000 00000100 10010000 00111110 01000000 00000000 00001101 10001110 10001000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111
```

In both of them i can recognize `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` trailer (`00FF`), but i can't establish if second frame has proper header at its beginning. My question: is the second compressed content actually headerless? and, in this case, in which way can I decompress this stream, maybe using raw deflate decompression (using inflateBack()) ?

Like i briefly explained in the comment below, the error was in the inflateReset() call, because it breaks synchronization between compressor and decompressor obtained using the 00FF trailer. Finally, correct version of the code would be:

```
int spdy_decompress_header_block( Byte* data, size_t data_len, unsigned char* processed,     size_t* processed_len, z_stream* decomp) {

if (!decomp) {
    // I should return error...
    spdy_log_error("Error occurred getting decompressor!!!");
    return -1;
}

char decomp_buffer[HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE];
size_t decompressed_len = 0;
int rv = -1;

decomp->next_in = data;
decomp->avail_in = data_len;
while (decomp->avail_in > 0) {

    decomp->next_out = (Byte*)decomp_buffer;
    decomp->avail_out = HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE;

    rv = inflate(decomp,Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

    if (rv == Z_NEED_DICT) {

        uLong dictionary_id = calculate_dictionary_id((Byte*)SPDY_dictionary, sizeof(SPDY_dictionary));

        if (decomp->adler == dictionary_id){

            rv = inflateSetDictionary(decomp, (Byte*)SPDY_dictionary, sizeof(SPDY_dictionary));
            rv = inflate(decomp, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        }

    }

    if ((rv == Z_OK) || ((rv == Z_BUF_ERROR) && (decomp->avail_in == 0))) {
        decompressed_len = HEADER_CHUNK_MAX_SIZE - decomp->avail_out;
        if (decompressed_len > 0) {
            memcpy(processed + *processed_len, decomp_buffer, decompressed_len);
            *processed_len += decompressed_len;
        }

    } else {
        if(rv == Z_DATA_ERROR){
            spdy_log_error("Error inflating headers:  Z_DATA_ERROR encountered" );
        }else{
            spdy_log_error("Error inflating headers!!!");
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
return *processed_len;
}
```

For more information, see interesting: http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.htm

Comment: Hi Ramon, I'm facing the same issue with SPDY frames on the second block of any trace I have been able to capture. Have you had any chance with tuning the zlib stream in order to make it work properly ?

Comment: I do have the same problem, were you able to find a solution?
I notice that your second block, the compression method is set to 10 (bin 1010), usually for deflate is should be 8 (1000) but yes I can recognize the trailer 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF which should mean it's a zlib compression. Anybody have some insight on this?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm really sorry for my absence, use of Z_SYNC_FLUSH flushing method causes generation of "chunks" (is not a proper definition) of a single zlib stream that compressor and decompressor can exchange in *exactly* same sequence. Every chunk has a trailer, so a decompressor can reognize end of chunk. Compressor and decompressor can get a kind of synchronization, for this reason the inflateReset(decomp) should NOT be present, it erases decompressor internal state, losing sychronization with respect to compressor flow of chunks. So i suggest you to initialize decompressor 1 time only.

Comment: if it can be useful, see my post on spdy-dev group: <https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/spdy-dev/Z_DATA_ERROR/spdy-dev/w712o1OiAgs/qCMet6eyX-cJ>